# r mutate only if columns exists

Tags: r

I don't know if there is existing method to do this

Let me give an example to show the case:

```
library(tidyverse)    
temp = data.frame(a=1:2,b = 3:4,c = 5:6)
```

I can use the mutate method in `tidyverse` and the expression list to add new columns

```
mutation_list = list(d = quote(a+b),e = quote(a+b+c))
result = temp %>% mutate(!!!mutation_list)
```

However, there are some cases in which some columns do not exists, for the simplest case, we miss column name `c`.

```
temp2 = temp[,c('a','b')]
```

I want the result calculate all possible vars based on existing vars,in this simple case, `d`, since `a` and `b` are there, while for `e`, it miss `c` so we can't calculate the result, we only return result with `a`,`b`,`d`; without throw error exception. Namely:

```
result = temp2 %>% mutate_onlyif_itcanfindvars(!!!mutation_list)
```

In this simple case we could easily find other ways to write it, however, if we have the expression list like 10000+,it must has some uniform way to do this.

The answer don't need to use `dplyr`, you can use `data.table` or any package you want, but we need to keep the temp in data.frame(or data.table or tibble) and mutation_list as expression list(if you use another form,please explain it)

Comment: Write a small check (comparison) based on `colnames(temp)`? Where is `l()` from?

Comment: @Friede it is list, I edit it. for column check, yes, but I was wondering if there is some existing method could do this, I think this is not rarely used case.

Comment: Is it always going to be `+` between the variables or it can be anything.

Comment: @Ronak Shah Hi, could be any expressions, like pmax or other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
safely_transmute <- safely(transmute)

cbind(
  temp,
  imap(
      mutation_list,
    ~ {
      temp |>
        safely_transmute(!!.y := !!.x) |>
        getElement("result")                                             
    }
  ) |>
    list_cbind()
)
```

---

This one should work for simple cases like the one in the question:

```
mutate_if_possible <- function(data, pattern) {
  
  for (calc in seq_along(pattern)) {
    
    used_columns <- str_subset(all.names(pattern[calc]), "[:alpha:]")
    
    if (!all(used_columns %in% names(data))) {
      next
    }
    
    data <- data |>
      mutate(!!!pattern[calc])
  }
  
  data
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a simple function that would modify the mutation list before being evaluated:

```
ml_modify <- function(mut_list){
  lapply(mut_list, \(x)call('tryCatch', x, error = \(.){}))
}

temp %>%
  mutate(!!!ml_modify(mutation_list))

  a b c d  e
1 1 3 5 4  9
2 2 4 6 6 12

temp2 %>%
  mutate(!!!ml_modify(mutation_list))

  a b d
1 1 3 4
2 2 4 6
```

Comment: This is a really slick way to do it! Nice one.

Comment: Hi,what does \ in \\(x) mean here?

Comment: What is the difference between \(x) and \(.)

Comment: There is no difference - it would be equivalent to write `error = function(x) {}` and `error = function(.) {}`. `.` is just the argument name of the function.

Comment: @cloudscomputes check the comment by @diomedesdata. `\(x)` is a shortform for `function(x)`.

Comment: I got what you mean, \\(.) is like function(x) replace x with .; in which . is also a valid R object name. \ is used to replace function in R after 4.1.0.

Comment: @cloudscomputes consider accepting one of the answers to close the question

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution using the new parameterised expressions (needing version >= 1.15.0), and a try statement to skip any invalid expressions.

This could also be extended to use `tryCatch` if you need to know which statements failed and what the errors were.

```
library(data.table) # data.table >= 1.15.0

temp = data.table(a = 1:2, b = 3:4, c = 5:6)

mutation_list = list(d = "a + b",
                     e = "a + b + c", 
                     f = "z")

for (i in 1:length(mutation_list)){
  try(
    temp[, let(var_name = eval(var_expr)), 
         env = list(var_name = names(mutation_list)[i], 
                    var_expr = parse(text = mutation_list[i]))],
    silent = TRUE
  )
}
```

There may be a cleaner way to use data.table parameterised expressions than the eval/parse approach here.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution assuming you can modify `mutation_list`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(temp)
ml <- list(d = c("a", "b"), e = c("a", "b", "c"))

for (i in seq_along(ml)) {
  vars <- ml[[i]]
  if (all(vars %in% names(temp))) {
    set(temp, j = names(ml)[i], value = temp[, rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = vars])
  }
}
```